# Errors in Firefox Add-on SDK when using cfx xpi whereas cfx run works great

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm a student at a University Institute of Technology in France and I'm very new to Firefox add-on development since I discovered it at the beginning of my work placement, a few days ago.

What I have to do is an add-on that allows employees of the company to organize SCRUM-meetings (it deals with agile software development).

For the moment, what I've done looks like this :

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/716589MeetingConfigurationPanel.png

The panel allows users to configure the settings of the meeting. I have also added a toolbar with action buttons and a frame in it, so that the meeting can start/be interrupted on the action buttons Onclick event. I have implemented countdown timers for each participants. There is also a "Next Speaker Button" that resets one of the timers when clicked...

And all seems to work fine when I use cfx run, but when I package the extension using cfx xpi... there are errors.

See : http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_585083outputExpected.png

**EDIT :** Problem with the link. I will update it as soon as possible.

Here is what I have in cfx run mode. All the buttons I declared in the code, along with the frame, are correctly displayed in the toolbar.

But in cfx xpi mode, some of the buttons are apparently "stuck" in what Browser Console refers to as "inner-toolbar" or something like that as I can read when I remove the extension.

That made me wonder if the buttons really were in the toolbar. And they were, according to the Debugger. So I've started thinking that my problem was compatibility with Firefox but I've checked both Firefox version and the em:maxVersion attribute in the install.rdf file that can be found when unpacking the xpi/zip file, and I've change the values so that they match, but it didn't resolve my problem.

I've read as many things as possible on topics related to the problem I'm now facing (including StackOverflow questions) but I have not been able to find a proper way to fix it up to now. Is my problem really different ? I have no idea. I might have done something bad trying to change things as they were intended to, I suppose. But it's unlikely.

And the thing is that I really need to make this add-on works, because it is the only thing I will work on during my work placement.

The solution to my problem may be very simple. Maybe I did something really stupid. I don't know. The only thing I know for sure is that I want to find what's going on, so that I will be able to deliver the first version as soon as possible.

Feel free to ask for more informations if necessary.

Thanks for reading.

Julien B.

Comment: Please, never again post image-only bug reports. Provide error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not technically an answer but SO won't let me comment.) You could try `cfx run`, then uninstalling the addon from the FF session it opened, then installing the xpi in that same session by doing a `file open` of the xpi (which will install it).  Have a feeling it will run in that case, which means there is a difference between your standard Firefox and the one cfx run opens.  There is a difference of course, because `cfx run` doesn't install all your other add-ons.  But it may be running a different Firefox version as well.  I mention this because when I run `cfx run` it always opens the beta version of FF which I downloaded at some point, and I don't know where its picking it up from.

Comment: You were right. It worked when I installed the .xpi file in the Firefox session opened by cfx run. Meaning there was some version incompatibilty issue. But my problem has changed since then : My add-on needs to run on a different computer than the one I'm using to develop it. I took the exact same FF setup file (FF Portable Edition 33.1.1) and even if it fixed the problem I had with the buttons, my add-on now only runs on my computer; On the other one, The panel appears and it is possible to configure the meeting, but clicking action buttons in the toolbar does nothing... I don't understand.

Comment: I mean, there's no other extension installed than mine on both my computer and the one I need to install the add-on. There's no plugin. It seems that there is no difference anymore between the two FF versions and the buttons now display correctly (in FF Portable Edition 33.1.1) but my add-on still refuses to run on an other computer than mine. For example, I change the value of document.body.border.style as timer countdown is running (it goes from green to red as time run out) but this only works on my computer. I also use window.alert at some point, and it only works on my computer...

Comment: Anyway, I suppose my first question is answered. I will probably ask a new question in order to know what could explain what I observe now. Thanks.